# How do you match a quote in a Sumologic regex query?

Tags: regex, sumologic

I'm having trouble matching a single quote, ' , or putting it in a character group in a Sumologic query.

For example, my query might look like

```
_sourceCategory="some_category" | where url matches /^\/stuff\/[\w']+\/.*/ and other_field="some_value"
```

The problem with this is that Sumologic will turn the characters after the single quote all red, as if it is the start of a string.
I've tried to escape it like `[\w\']+` in my character group, and it doesn't work.
I couldn't find any resources online about this. The closest thing I found is

https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Get-Started-with-Search/Search-Basics/Reference_a_Field_with_Special_Characters

But I'm not sure how to correspond this to my type of query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Sumologic [uses](https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Search-Query-Language/Search-Operators/where)  RE2 in the `where` clause, and [in RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), you can match any chars using hex character codes. So, you can use `\x27` to match a `'` char:

```js
| where url matches /^\/stuff\/[\w\x27]+\/.*/
```

See the Go lang (that uses RE2 regex library) [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pbcgzN/1).